Co-adding IFU data cubes
I was able to get my hands on some NIRspec IFU data cubes from JWST, and I was trying to combine two adjacent FOVs for getting the complete picture of my system. I used CASA prior to this to remove continuum emission from the source. I wanted to co-add them, and tried a few things:

reproject_and_coadd function of reproject package. Problem is, the function does not work for 3D cubes (dimensions - RA, DEC, WAVE) but rather on 2D images. Sending in the cubes slice by slice does not seem to be a good option at this point, I am assuming there is a better way to go about this.
MontagePy package by IPAC. Problem is, I don't think they account for different background levels of the two FOVs (which I think reproject_and_coadd accounts for?). Their background correction executables only work for 2D images, not 3D cubes. For example, here is what I see after combining my IFU cubes with MontagePy:


See the artifact in the middle? That is the overlap region of the two IFU cubes. I am stumped as of now as to how to rectify this, and I am pretty sure it is doable. I was curious if anyone has combined NIRSpec IFU cubes before with the JWST pipeline? If it is that I could combine the two IFU FOVs in the pipeline, then I might just do that (I wasn't able to find anything on this in the JWST documentation, they talked only about stacking 2D images)
Thanks!

If the wavelength axis is orthogonal to the spatial axes, I would recommend just using reproject since 3D resampling is much less efficient than multiple 2D resampling.

Yes, the wavelength axis is orthogonal to the spatial axes, no issues there. However, mosaicking is not really a thing mentioned in the documentation of reproject, for 3D spectral cubes (the function mentioned, as far as I've played with it, takes in only 2D images). I can perhaps use reproject_and_coadd only if I send in the cube wavelength by wavelength.

Yeah, unfortunately I think that is the best option right now. I agree it would be nice if reproject could vectorized along the wavelength axis, but alas it has not been implemented yet.
